# @Html.DropDownListFor using ViewBag SelectedListItem the selected item is not shown

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My code is the following:

**Controller:**

```
foreach (Employee engineer in engineers)
{                       
       if (!model.Customer.PrimaryEngineerId.Equals(engineer.EmployeeId)) 
       {
            engineersListPrimary.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = engineer.FirstName + ' ' + engineer.LastName, Value = engineer.EmployeeId, Selected = false});
       }
       else
       {
            engineersListPrimary.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = engineer.FirstName + ' ' + engineer.LastName, Value = engineer.EmployeeId, Selected = true });
       }                 
}
ViewBag.engineersListPrimary = engineersListPrimary;
return View(model);
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.PrimaryEngineer, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.engineersListPrimary, new { style = "width:100%;"})
```

After searching a lot and trying a bunch of different ways I couldn't manage to print the selected value wished.

**Problem:**

The selected value is not shown in the *DropDownListFor* used in the *View*.

After debugging I have checked that the *engineersListPrimary* is correctly filled (the *Selected = true* row is inserted correctly) so the problem must remain in the *View*.

Any suggestions?? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I assume the missing comma after `m => m.Customer.PrimaryEngineer` is just a typo in the question. If you put a breakpoint on the `@Html.DropDownListFor` line, does `ViewBag.engineersListPrimary` still look correct?

Comment: Yes, the comma was in my code, I have correct it the posted code. The `ViewBag.engineersListPrimary` is correctly filled with the _Selected = true_ value correctly. But as @Andrei said, I had to change `m => m.Customer.PrimaryEngineer` to `m => m.Customer.PrimaryEngineerId` and it fill the selected value automatically. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this expression:

```
m => m.Customer.PrimaryEngineer
```

DropDownListFor expects this lambda to give the property that you are trying to set by this input control. In your case this is not the `m.Customer.PrimaryEngineer` but `m.Customer.PrimaryEngineerId`, so this should fix it:

```
m => m.Customer.PrimaryEngineerId
```

Also note that there is no need to set `Selected` property of your list items while using DropDownListFor, as this helper can derive selected item based on the provided model value.

Comment: Yes it works! Even if the _ViewBag_ has not set the attribute Selected = true, it correctly selects the Engineer in the _DropDownListFor_. I imagine that internally set the value to _Selected = true_, no? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Alvykun, I have not checked, frankly. But your assumption looks highly probable to me

Comment: @Alvykun instead of making so mess and iterating use ``SelectList`` class it is for this purpose, also check my post for more clarification

Answer (score 1):

The best way what i see is to just do it using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of `SelectList()`.

Replace your foreach loop code with this and you are good to go:

```
ViewBag.engineersListPrimary = new SelectList(engineers,
                                             "EmployeeId",
                                             "FirstName",
                                             model.Customer.PrimaryEngineerId);
return View(model);
```

and in View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.PrimaryEngineer, 
                           ViewBag.engineersListPrimary as SelectList, 
                           new { style = "width:100%;"})
```

### MSDN Docs:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    Object selectedValue
)
```

See [SelectList class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedID, new SelectList(model.PrimaryEngineer, "Value", "Text"), "optionalLabel",  new { style = "width:100%;"})
```